# Unable to set div tag text dynamically on above of specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

Hi I have `RoundedButton` in which I have div tag where text should be set dynamically, below of this there is button.

If you see `App.js` I have re-used this component three times. When user click on any button then "User selected" text should be on above of that button. As of now, no matter on what button I am clicking it is showing on above of first button.

RoundedButton.js

```
class RoundedButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _handleButtonClick(item) {
    this.props.clickitem(item.buttonText);
    //document.getElementById("who_played").innerHTML = "User selected";
  }

  render() {
    let buttonText = this.props.text;
    return (
      <div className="WhoPlayed">
        <div id="who_played" style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} />
        <div>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="Button"
            onClick={this._handleButtonClick.bind(this, { buttonText })}
          >
            {buttonText}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RoundedButton;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import RoundedButton from "./RoundedButton";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as actions from "./actions/index";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      status: ""
    };
    this.clickitem = this.clickitem.bind(this);
  }

  clickitem(user) {
    var url = "http://localhost:4000/generate-random";
    document.getElementById("who_played").innerHTML = "User selected";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        var computer = data.item;
        if (
          (user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") ||
          (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock") ||
          (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Paper")
        ) {
          this.props.increment();
        } else if (user === computer) {
          this.props.doNothing();
        } else {
          this.props.decrement();
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="CenterDiv">
        <div className="AppTitle">
          <b>Score: {this.props.score}</b>
          <div>
            <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
            <RoundedButton text="Paper" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
            <RoundedButton text="Scissors" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          </div>

          <div className="Status">{this.props.status}</div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { score: state.score, status: state.status };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

Current State:

[image]

Expected State:

[image]

Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the posted code:

1. The rendered HTML has three `RoundedButton` elements, each of which has a div with `id="who_played"`. ID's should be unique in an HTML document. This is why you're seeing the text always appear above the first button. If you indeed want to set the label using `getElementById`, use unique IDs for each button.
2. Since React is declarative, there really shouldn't be any need to use the DOM API to set the label. Use state instead. As an example:

   ```
   class App extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
               score: 0,
               status: "",
               selected: ""
           };
           this.clickitem = this.clickitem.bind(this);
       }

       clickitem(item) {
           this.setState({ selected: item });
           ...rest of code...
       }

       render() {
           return (
               <div className="CenterDiv">
               <div className="AppTitle">
                   <b>Score: {this.props.score}</b>
                   <div>
                   <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} selected={this.state.selected === "Rock"} />
                   <RoundedButton text="Paper" clickitem={this.clickitem} selected={this.state.selected === "Paper"}/>
                   <RoundedButton text="Scissors" clickitem={this.clickitem} selected={this.state.selected === "Scissors"} />
                   </div>

                   <div className="Status">{this.props.status}</div>

               </div>
               </div>
           );
       }
   }

   class RoundedButton extends Component {
       _handleButtonClick(item) {
           this.props.clickitem(item.buttonText);
       }

       render() {
           let buttonText = this.props.text;
           return (
               <div className="WhoPlayed">
               <div id="who_played" style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>{this.props.selected? "User Selected": ""}</div>
               <div>
                   <button
                   type="button"
                   className="Button"
                   onClick={this._handleButtonClick.bind(this, { buttonText })}
                   >
                   {buttonText}
                   </button>
               </div>
               </div>
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I need "user selected" and "computer selected" - computer selected value is here `var computer = data.item;`

Comment: Shouldn't it `this.props.selected` ? in RoundedButton ?

Comment: Thanks. This is ok for userSelected but how to do if I want computer selected also text like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pta7M.png

Comment: Just maintain `userSelected` and `computerSelected` as state in `App`.  Then you can do something like: `<RoundedButton label={this.state.userSelected === "Rock"? "User Selected": (this.state.computerSelected === "Rock"? "Computer Selected": "")} />`